# Handle invalid characters from filename in unix

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix, special-characters

I need to do some linux command operations on files having "!" like characters in filename. But whenever I am trying to execute the commands, I am getting below error.

```
[root@ATD-6000 ~]# cat a!aapoorv.txt
-bash: !aapoorv.txt: event not found
```

I am executing these commands in python using paramiko module. I can't use raw string r'filestringname', as I am reading string name from db itself.

How to escape/handle these king of characters using python/bash.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: It doesn't .

Comment: `open("a!aapoorv.txt")` should work just fine

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
cat a\!aapoorv.txt
```

or this

```
cat 'a!aapoorv.txt'
```

> Note that while `cat a\!aapoorv.txt` works in all shells that implement that csh-style history expansion, `cat 'a!aapoorv.txt'` doesn't work in csh/tcsh.

for more information, you can see `man bash` about the **QUOTING**.

Here is some of that document:

> Quoting  is  used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words to the shell.
>
> Quoting can be used to disable spe‐cial treatment for special characters, to prevent reserved words from being recognized as such, and to prevent  parameter  expan‐sion.

And here is the output:

```
[kevin@Arch test]$ ls
a!aapoorv.txt
[kevin@Arch test]$ cat a\!aapoorv.txt 
Hello, This is a test
[kevin@Arch test]$ cat 'a!aapoorv.txt'
Hello, This is a test
```

On Python, you don't need to escape the special character, here is a test:

```
>>> with open('a!aapoorv.txt') as f:
...     f.read()
...     
... 
'Hello, This is a test\n'
>>> with open(r'a!aapoorv.txt') as f:
...     f.read()
...     
... 
'Hello, This is a test\n'
>>>
```

Comment: do all of them work? i have tested the 3rd one for creating a file and it doesn't work.

Comment: The last one (with double quotes) is not going to work (you'd still need to escape the `!` with a backslash). Another option is to disable history expansion with `set +H`.

Comment: Yes they can all work, let me edit my answer and add some more info and output.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've tried it again, I think you're right. Thanks :)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I've just add them to my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use singlequotes ' ':

```
$ cat 'a!aapoorv.txt'
cat: a!aapoorv.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bash, you need to use the escaping methods (single quotes or backslash) described by the other answers.

In Python, you shouldn't need to use raw strings or any other type of escaping to open a file with special chars.

For example, this works fine:

```
my_f_contents = open("a!aapoorv.txt").read()
```